# Auto link specific words and phrases

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I use jQuery, another library or standard javascript to list a series of words and phrases that I would like to be auto linked?

For example:

Word / phrase 1: link to www.something.com 
Word / phrase 2: link to www.somethingelse.com 
Word / phrase 3: link to www.anotherlink.org

And so on.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the javascript replace() function.

```
$("#myid").html().replace('word one', '<a href="http://www.something.com">word one</a>');
```

See http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-replace.php for more information.

**EDIT**

The above only replaces the first instance of "word one".  To replace everything, you'll need to use regular expressions.

```
$("#myid").html().replace(/word one/g, '<a href="http://www.something.com">word one</a>');
```

Replace "word one" with the text you want to replace.

**EDIT 2**

To answer your question in the comment, you need to capture the output.  For example:

```
 $("#myid").html($("#myid").html().replace(/word one/g, '<a href="http://www.something.com">word one</a>'));
```

replace() isn't part of jQuery, and as such doesn't actually modify the DOM.  replace() returns the modified string, so you need to do the leg work to write the modified string back to the page.